# When is SystemTimers.Timer considered garbageif no reference is saved?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, system.timers.timer

I am very curious to know when a System.Timers.Timer is considered garbage and therefor collected by the Garbage Collector if I do not store a reference to it, but it is Enabled. 
But at what point is my Timer considered garbage?

Consider the following code:

```
public void TriggerUpdateStatus() {
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "*";
    new Timer() {
        Interval = 1000,
        Enabled = true
    }.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(
        (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) => {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "";
            Timer t = ((System.Timers.Timer) sender);
            t.Stop();
            t.Dispose();//Is this needed?
        });
}
```

This block of code will run once every two seconds when my code triggers an update, it then adds a star character in the bottom corner of my form, indicating that the connection is alive and well. I create a Timer with no reference that will simply remove the star again after a second, stop it self and dispose of itself.

Comment: How/why could it ever be considered garbage while it is running???

Comment: On Line 10, it stops itself and on line 11 it disposes itself.

Comment: You asked: _if I do not store a reference to it, but it is Enabled_. Now which is it?

Comment: Your `Timer` object will become eligible for the garbage collection even before the method returns (based on your code). However, you cannot exactly know when this object will be collected. The GC in .NET is non-deterministic in this way. Note that the `Timer` is a `Component` which has a finalizer that will automatically disable the running timer if it will be running at the time of collection (to be more exact, when the finalizer queue will be processed).

Answer (score 0):

No, `t.Dispose()`, isn't necessary, it will be collected regardless.

The question itself seems to convey a deep misunderstanding about how the GC and `Dispose` work (I stress the word *seems*). The GC has absolutely no idea what `Dispose` does and couldn`t care less. That an object is disposed or not doesn't come in to play as to wether that particular object is elegible for collection; these are two completely orthogonal concepts.

Dispose is there as a mechanism to release unmanaged resources, it has nothing to do with how the garbage collector works.

If that is clear, then `Dispose`, although polite, isn't even strictly necessary; `Dispose` (or the needed part of it) will run anyway when the timer is eventually collected (the object is unreachable and short lived so it shouldn't take too long), put in the finalizer queue and finalized in some undetermined future; it is polite and recommended to dispose in order to deterministically release all unmanaged resources associated with the object instead of relying on whenever the finalizer queue decides to run, which brings up the next point:

Why are you newing up a `Timer` every two seconds and then disposing it immediately? Wouldn't it be much easier to have one single timer and reset it every time?

Comment: So If i read what you said right, as soon as the timer stops it will be collected, or can I run into times where it is collected before the timer stops? To answer your question, I know it's an outrageous way to solve a problem, I tried a few things and always ran into problems with the two timers getting out of sync or one timer would just stop working completely.